# Creating a poll system using PircBot

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to create a poll system using PircBot. 
So far my code is this:

```
if (message.startsWith("!poll")) {
    String polly = message.substring(6);
    String[] vote = polly.split(" ");
    String vote1 = vote[0];
    String vote2 = vote[1];
}
```

Which splits the strings so that someone can type !poll "option1 option2" for example and it will be split into vote1 = option1 and vote2 = option2.

I'm kind of lost from here. Am I even heading in the right direction for creating a voting system?

I figure that I'd have a separate statement as follows.

```
 if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!vote " + option1))
```

But I'm not sure where to go with that either.

Comment: It will only work when providing 2 options. If the user only enters one, your application will throw an exception.

Comment: @User404 How do I fix that then? Thanks.

Comment: @quibblify Well, you can just catch the exception and ignore it. Then naturally you'll need to keep your polls in memory somehow.

Comment: Do you have a real problem. Right now this looks like you wqnt to learn how to do this, and this isn't the right place for this.